# Programa para trocar duas colunas de uma matriz como lista de listas: nada acontece!

Tags: python, python-3.x, matriz

O que eu fiz (Não é para usar numpy):

```
from random import randint
    matriz = []
    n = m =5#linhas colunas
    
    #inicializando
    temp = [i for i in n*[0]]
    for i in range(n):
        matriz.append(temp.copy())################atencao para o copy, senao da problema nos prox passos
        #a matriz vaI FICAR com todas as listas IGUAIS
    
    for i in range(n):#linha
        for j in range(m):#coluna
            ele = randint(0, 30)
            print(f"Inserindo elemento da {i}{j}: {ele}")
            matriz[i][j] = ele
    print()
    print(" A matriz criada foi: ")
    print()
    for vetor in matriz:
        print(vetor)

    #trocar a primeira e a quarta coluna;
    matriz[:][0], matriz[:][3] = matriz[:][3],matriz[:][0] #Nao fez NADA na matriz
    matriz
```

Entrada:

```
[[2, 23, 8, 14, 6],
 [26, 26, 29, 10, 2],
 [12, 9, 11, 8, 23],
 [26, 28, 3, 11, 30],
 [23, 19, 0, 1, 29]]
```

Saída:

```
[[2, 23, 8, 14, 6],
 [26, 26, 29, 10, 2],
 [12, 9, 11, 8, 23],
 [26, 28, 3, 11, 30],
 [23, 19, 0, 1, 29]]
```

No entando, a matriz **não** foi alterada. O que houve? Alguma forma de resolver isso? Acredito que seja um problema com o slice das listas mas não sei explicar.

Comment: `matriz[:]` cria uma cópia da matriz (ou seja, vc altera a cópia, não a original), mas como vc não atribui esta cópia em nenhuma variável, ela acaba se perdendo. De qualquer forma, como vc está tentando fazer, ele vai trocar as linhas, e não as colunas. No seu exemplo, se fosse para trocar as colunas, o resultado deveria ser `[[14, 23, 8, 2, 6], [10, 26, 29, 26, 2], [8, 9, 11, 12, 23], [11, 28, 3, 26, 30], [1, 19, 0, 23, 29]]`, certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matriz[:]` cria uma cópia da matriz (ou seja, vc altera a cópia, não a original), mas como vc não atribui esta cópia em nenhuma variável, ela acaba se perdendo.

Você até poderia fazer `matriz[0], matriz[3] = matriz[3], matriz[0]`, para modificar a matriz original, porém isso vai trocar as **linhas**, e não as colunas.

Usando a matriz do seu exemplo:

```py
matriz = [
 [2, 23, 8, 14, 6],
 [26, 26, 29, 10, 2],
 [12, 9, 11, 8, 23],
 [26, 28, 3, 11, 30],
 [23, 19, 0, 1, 29]
]

matriz[0], matriz[3] = matriz[3], matriz[0]
for linha in matriz:
    for n in linha:
        print(f'{n:4}', end='')
    print()
```

O resultado será:

```
  26  28   3  11  30
  26  26  29  10   2
  12   9  11   8  23
   2  23   8  14   6
  23  19   0   1  29
```

Repare que o que mudou foi a primeira e quarta linhas. Se você quiser mudar as colunas, terá que percorrer todas as linhas e mudar o primeiro e quarto elementos de cada uma:

```py
matriz = [
 [2, 23, 8, 14, 6],
 [26, 26, 29, 10, 2],
 [12, 9, 11, 8, 23],
 [26, 28, 3, 11, 30],
 [23, 19, 0, 1, 29]
]

# em todas as linhas, trocar os elementos da primeira e quarta colunas
for linha in matriz:
    linha[0], linha[3] = linha[3], linha[0]

for linha in matriz:
    for n in linha:
        print(f'{n:4}', end='')
    print()
```

E agora sim ele troca as colunas:

```
  14  23   8   2   6
  10  26  29  26   2
   8   9  11  12  23
  11  28   3  26  30
   1  19   0  23  29
```

---

Por fim, não diretamente relacionado, mas listas são dinâmicas e você não precisa alocar espaço antes. Para criar a matriz, poderia ser assim:

```py
from random import randint

matriz = []
n = m = 5 # linhas colunas
for i in range(n):
    linha = [] # cria uma nova linha
    for j in range(m): # adiciona as colunas na linha
        elemento = randint(0, 30)
        print(f"Inserindo elemento da {i}{j}: {elemento}")
        linha.append(elemento)
    # adiciona a nova linha na matriz
    matriz.append(linha)
```

Comment: esclareceu muito! Realmente nao entendi pq haviam negativado a pergunta! VOu estudar a sua resposta e volto para marcar como resolvido